# Zeppelin change port already in use by Spark Master

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I start zeppelin on AWS, It starts on port 8080, but there is Spark Master so it says port already in use... I tried changing port in zeppelin in config files, in "zeppelin-site.xml.template"

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
  <value>8050</value>
  <description>Server port.</description>
</property>
```

I made it too in "zeppelin-env.sh.template" adding the env line for the same port.

When I start zeppelin, I get OK, but if I see the open ports, It doesn't appear 8050 anywhere, so looks like It is still trying to deploy on port 8080, where Spark Master is...

Someone who got zeppelin not ignoring changed port?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You likely need to copy the `.template` files, e.g. copy your modified `zeppelin-env.sh.template` to `zeppelin-env.sh` and `zeppelin-site.xml.template` to `zeppelin-site.xml`.

Comment: Oh god how I did not see that, thank you very much you saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

From your zeppelin installation dir (example on my computer its: `zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all`):

```
cp conf/zeppelin-env.sh.template conf/zeppelin-env.sh
vi conf/zeppelin-env.sh
```

Add the following parameter:

```
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8180 # Add this line to zeppelin-env.sh
```

restart zeppelin you should now be able to access it over:

http://localhost:8180

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, both [documented](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/install/install.html#Configure) ways should work:

- create `conf/zeppelin-site.xml` with `zeppelin.server.port` property
- create `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` and export `ZEPPELIN_PORT` env variable

and restarting Zeppelin

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems to be a little old, so I'm putting here the solution I found, in case it's useful for others:

It is possible to define variables (including port) either `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` or in `conf/zeppelin-site.xml`. The `zeppelin-env` takes priority if both are defined.

Source:

http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/snapshot/install/configuration.html

Comment: Your source link is not found